# Will ad show up in above config. or it will directly start the next activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, development-environment

New Game is a button in xml which on clicking the newGame will run.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:onClick="newGame"
        android:text="@string/newgame" />


  public void newGame(View view) {
        if (startAppAd != null){
               startAppAd.show();
               startAppAd = null;
            }
         Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Question is that , will ad show up in above config. or it will directly start the next activity ?? If not please suggest a way to show ad on clicking the button & after that start a new activity.
Thanks in advance

( I have tried in emulator but it does not show up , i dont know if problem is becoz of internet )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impression will be there but we will not able to see it as there is no pause.